# I can't understand GroupJoin where i will need it in database relationships

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

I am thinking 5-6 hours to understand something about GroupJoin. I am talking about query with linq for Database tables.I understand what Join and GroupJoin does but I really couldn't understand where i will need it.I feel that Join does all what i will need but if there is something which Join can't without GroupJoin so i feel that situation is meaningless or useless.

For example:

Persons table in relation with Phones  and Phones table hold foreign keys of Persons and one person can have one more phone number.If we want to brings all persons who has phone numbers and who hasn't too so we will need GroupJOin but  what for we will need this query ?

Can u give me good reason , example or explenation for using GroupJoin ?

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN:

> In relational database terms, Join implements an inner join, a type of join in which only those objects that have a match in the other data set are returned. The GroupJoin method has no direct equivalent in relational database terms, but it implements a superset of inner joins and left outer joins.

So, if you've ever had a reason to use an outer join in SQL, you would likely use GroupJoin for similar purposes in Linq.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you'd write:

```
SELECT *
FROM Persons p LEFT JOIN Phones ph on p.PersonID = ph.PersonID
```

You'd get a row column shape with some rows having null phone numbers, and some rows having the same Person as other rows.

```
Bob, null
Joe,  111-1111
Mike, 222-2222
Mike, 333-3333
Mike, 444-4444
```

---

In LinqToSql, you'd write:

```
from p in Persons
join ph in Phones on p.PersonID equals ph.PersonID into phones
select new {Person = p, Phones = phones.ToList()};
```

You'd get one person instance per person and one phone instance per phone, all properly related.

```
Bob, [] <- (empty)
Joe, [111-1111]
Mike, [222-2222, 333-3333, 444-4444]
```

Comment: It was nice explenation that only one person instance will come for per person.Now i got it.If we would use just join we sometimes could get one more instance for a person and plus we wouldn't get all persons list right ? This time another question appear in my mind.Why we need this query ? Isn't it meaningless ?If we want to see persons who has phones has means.If we want to see persons who hasn't phone numbers has means too.But querying all persons whether who has phone number or not hasn't any mean to me .Even querying all persons has meaning to me. and this is what i can't still understand

Comment: The meaning of group join in terms of Database IO/plan is equivalent to left join.  Left join isn't meaningless.  The meaning of the group join in terms of result shape is significantly different from left join.  In the object world - a heirarchical result shape is frequently important for data cohesion, unlike in the data world where a result row has properties from all the columns that are involved.

Comment: If you don't get it right away, that's ok.  GroupJoin threw me for a loop when I was learning Linq, too.